# Need to access GAE logs programmatically

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, logging, error-logging

we have a GWT application hosted in GAE. We use gwt-log (http://
code.google.com/p/gwt-log/) to log our client side and server side
exceptions. What we need to do is to run a cron job every day at the
midnight to create a report on all the exceptions (ex. listing source,
exception time, count, etc). In order to do this, we need to access
GAE logs promrammatically through API call or something from our
server side code. Is this possible?
Is the log data accessible?

If this is not possible, what is a best way to summarize errors in the
logs?

Thank you so much.

Comment: This works in GAE Python, I don't know if there's a Java version: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/python/recording_exceptions_with_ereporter.html  At least you can see how they implemented the idea.

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to configure this with we.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ereporter module Calvin links to shows how to do this in Python. What it does isn't reading logs programmatically: instead, it registers a custom log handler which captures all exception logs and stores them in the datastore. Then, a cron job rolls up exceptions that occurred in that interval and emails them to an administrator.

You should be able to apply the same technique in java with the logging infrastructure, without having to be able to programmatically read the logs.

Comment: Could you show me an example for how to do this? Thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since you need to invoke a $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/ereporter/report_generator.py probably the same way Java app invokes a Servlet.

Comment: I just did a quick research, this is not supported by Java. Reference: http://code.google.com/appengine/tools_tips.html

Comment: @Mayumi It definitely is - check the docs for Java's logging infrastructure. What does the tools and tips page have to do with it?

Comment: But Java requires a Servlet to handle the server side request/response. In the instruction we need to invoke $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/ereporter/report_generator.py which is Python file, which requires a Python app. I don't think app engine is configured to allow Java app to invoke a .py file.

Comment: @Mayumi I'm not suggesting using ereporter - I'm suggesting porting it to Java. What it does is quite straightforward, and equally applicable to the Java runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the [LogService API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logservice/).

It offers methods to examine an application's request logs and application logs.